# Force a redirect to the installation page in CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect, installation, codeigniter-3

It's me again. I come here with another problem :/ I have a script to install my application. Everything works fine, after the installation is finished the script resets the directory permissions to 600 so that the application cannot be reinstalled. I also wanted to do that when there is an installer folder and it does not have the 600 permissions, it takes me to the installation page. I cannot explain it otherwise.

Here is the code to redirect to the installation page:

```
if(is_dir('../../install/') && substr(decoct(fileperms('../../install/')), -4) !== 600) {
    $base_url = ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on") ? "https" : "http");
    $base_url .= "://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $base_url .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), "", $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
    $base_url = str_replace('admin/auth', '', $base_url);
    sleep(1);
    header('Location:' . $base_url . '/install');
}
```

I added this code to the top of index.php but it doesn't work. As if it loads last, as if something comes first. Because if there is no database set, it spits out an error that it cannot connect, and they are set only after installation. How can I force a transfer to the install page if there is a directory with the installer files and it doesn't have chmod 600?

Thank you in advance for any help ;) Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You should extend CI_Controller

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller

Notice how MY_ is all upper-case. Make sure this file is saved as application/core/MY_Controller.php, again note the case.

Than put that code into the __constructor of MY_Controller

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. Unless I'm doing something wrong. I created application/core/MY_Controller.php and put in it:

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
  parent::__construct();
                ..... (the code that was above)
 }
}

and in the file application/controllers/Home.php: 
class Home extends MY_Controller { code.... }

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I added the code below to index.php

```
if(is_dir('install/') && substr(decoct(fileperms('install/')), -4) !== 600) {
    $base_url = ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on") ? "https" : "http");
    $base_url .= "://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $base_url .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), "", $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
    $base_url = str_replace('admin/auth', '', $base_url);
    die('Instalator wykryty. Proszę przejść do <a href="' . $base_url . 'install">instalacji sklepu</a>');
}
```